# add gdb package to riscv image using yocto

Tags: gdb, yocto, riscv, yocto-recipe

I am new to Yocto, trying to add `gdb` to the resulting image using `IMAGE_INSTALL_append="gdb"` in `local.conf`.

I got the following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'python-compilegdb' (but /home/osdev/riscv-poky/build/../meta-riscv/recipes-core/images/core-image-riscv.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)

NOTE: Runtime target 'python-compilegdb' is unbuildable, removing...

Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['python-compilegdb']
ERROR: Required build target 'core-image-riscv' has no buildable providers.

Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['core-image-riscv', 'python-compilegdb']
```

How can I resolve this error?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The override-style append you used literally only appends the string you give to the variable value: this means you need to add a prepending space yourself:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " gdb"
```